# How to send email from custom API

Tags: api, email, rest-api

I created a custom API that collects information from a form. How can I send that information to the **admin's email** ?

The API is working fine, but I don't know how to combine it with the email function.

This is my API interface in `/vendor_name/module_name/Api/ConfiguratorPrint.php`

```
<?php
namespace ConfiguratorPrint\Rest\Api;

interface ConfiguratorInterface
{
/**
 * Returns user configurator
 *
 * @api
 * @param string $config_name Users name.
 * @param string $config_email Users email.
 * @param string $config_phone Users phone.
 * @param string $config_shape Users shape.
 * @param string $config_message Users message.
 * @param string $config_upload Users upload.
 * @return string return user configurator.
 */
public function getConfigData($config_name,$config_email,$config_phone,$config_shape,$config_message,$config_upload);
}
```

This is my API model in `/vendor_name/module_name/Model/Configurator.php`

```
<?php
namespace ConfiguratorPrint\Rest\Model;
use ConfiguratorPrint\Rest\Api\ConfiguratorInterface;

class Configurator implements ConfiguratorInterface
{
/**
 * Returns user configurator
 *
 * @api
 * @param string $config_name Users name.
 * @param string $config_email Users email.
 * @param string $config_phone Users phone.
 * @param string $config_shape Users shape.
 * @param string $config_message Users message.
 * @param string $config_upload Users upload.
 * @return string return user configurator.
 */
public function getConfigData($config_name, $config_email, $config_phone, $config_shape, $config_message, $config_upload) {

    try {

        // Put incomming data in array
        $configFields = array();
        if($config_name){$configFields['config_name'] = $config_name;}
        if($config_email){$configFields['config_email'] = $config_email;}
        if($config_phone){$configFields['config_phone'] = $config_phone;}
        if($config_shape){$configFields['config_shape'] = $config_shape;}
        if($config_message){$configFields['config_message'] = $config_message;}
        if($config_upload){$configFields['config_upload'] = json_decode($config_upload);}

        // Looping trough upladed images and decoding
        $length = count($configFields['config_upload']);
        for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
            $imgData = $configFields['config_upload'][$i];

            list($type, $imgData) = explode(';', $imgData);
            list(, $imgData)      = explode(',', $imgData);
            $imgData = base64_decode($imgData);

        }

    } 

    catch(Exception $e){
        throw $e;
    }
 }
}
```

And this is my send email code in `/vendor_name/module_name/Controller/Index/send_email.php`

```
<?php

namespace ConfiguratorPrint\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Sendemail extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
 */
protected $_request;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
 */
protected $_transportBuilder;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    , \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    , \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    , \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
)
{
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('configurator_email_template')
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
        ->setTemplateVars(
            [
                'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
            ]
        )
        ->setFrom('customer@gmail.com')
        // you can config general email address in Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
        ->addTo('admin@gmail.com', 'Store Name')
        ->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();
    return $this;
 }
}
```

And this the code that POST's data to API, I'm using angular.

```
configurate(model, isValid:boolean) {
if(isValid) {

  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let body = {
    "config_name": model.name,
    "config_email": model.email,
    "config_phone": model.phone,
    "config_shape": model.shape,
    "config_message": model.message,
    "config_upload": JSON.stringify(this.imageSrc)
  };

  return this.http.post(this.baseApiUrl + 'rest/V1/configurator', body, {headers: headers}
      ).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log("Configurator", data);
            $('.loader').hide();
            $('.success-message').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
              $('.success-message').hide();
            }, 5000);
          },
        err => { 
          console.log(err);
        },
        () => { 

        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just a question. You say you collect it from a form. But where do you sync your api? Can i see that code? Because you will need to make a model that sends the mail but is triggered by your api

Comment: thank you for your fast reply, I edited the above code, I allready have a Model for my API, do I need a Model for the send mail function ? I'm a frontend developer so this is all new stuff for me.

Comment: Well first off all your namespaces are a bit weird. lets say your module is Test_Api then you need to have the folders Test/Api/... And your namespaces are Test/Api/... Secondly what kind of API are you using? I succesfully made a REST API connection to another database and imported that into Magento but it was done trough an Controller since you need a callback URL to obtain the data with an API key

Comment: I'm using REST API, and its working fine, but I don't know how to trigger the mail sending function, or if its even possible...

Comment: oh sure its possible. I'm using a command do to so , i will tell you in an answer how i do it. It won't be about how to send a mail but how to trigger an action

Comment: ok, please tell me how you trigger an action

Comment: I hope this will help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, probably not best practice, but it works. I added code from controller to the API model, and now it send emails with multiple attachments after you call API.

Here is API model code:

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

use VendorName\ModuleName\Api\ConfiguratorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Configurator extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements 
ConfiguratorInterface
{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
 */
protected $_request;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
 */
protected $_transportBuilder;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

/**
 * Returns user configurator
 *
 * @api
 * @param string $config_name Users name.
 * @param string $config_email Users email.
 * @param string $config_phone Users phone.
 * @param string $config_shape Users shape.
 * @param string $config_message Users message.
 * @param string $config_upload Users upload.
 * @return string return user configurator.
 */
public function getConfigData($config_name, $config_email, $config_phone, $config_shape, $config_message, $config_upload) {

    try {

        // Put incomming data in array
        global $configFields;
        $configFields = array();
        if($config_name){$configFields['config_name'] = $config_name;}
        if($config_email){$configFields['config_email'] = $config_email;}
        if($config_phone){$configFields['config_phone'] = $config_phone;}
        if($config_shape){$configFields['config_shape'] = $config_shape;}
        if($config_message){$configFields['config_message'] = $config_message;}
        if($config_upload){$configFields['config_upload'] = json_decode($config_upload);} else {$configFields['config_upload'] = null;}

        return $this->execute();

    }

    catch(Exception $e){
        throw $e;
    }
}

/**
* Send configurator email
*
* @return string
* @throws \Exception
*/ 
public function execute()
{
    try {
        global $configFields;

        // Looping trough upladed images and decoding
        $length = count($configFields['config_upload']);
        for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
            $imgData = $configFields['config_upload'][$i];

            list($type, $imgData) = explode(';', $imgData);
            list(, $imgData)      = explode(',', $imgData);
            $imgData = base64_decode($imgData);

            // Add images to mail
            $this->_transportBuilder->addAttachment($imgData,'Attachment'. $i);
        }

        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $sender = [
            'name'  => $configFields['config_name'],
            'email' => $configFields['config_email'],
            ];

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('configurator_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
            ->setTemplateVars(
                [
                    'store'         => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
                    'phone'         => $configFields['config_phone'],
                    'shape'         => $configFields['config_shape'],
                    'message'       => $configFields['config_message'],
                ]
            )
            ->setFrom($sender)
            // you can config general email address in Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
            ->addTo('general')
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        return 'Message sent!';
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

And here is code for sending attachment:

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
/**
* @param string $imgString
* @param string $filename
* @return mixed
*/
public function addAttachment($imgString, $filename)
{
   If ($filename == '') {
       $filename="attachment";
   }
   $this->message->createAttachment(
       $imgString,
       'application/png',
       \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
       \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
       $filename.'.png'
   );
   return $this;
  }
}
```

And here is di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="VendorName\ModuleName\Api\ConfiguratorInterface"
            type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Configurator" />
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder"
            type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

So from my understanding you need to send a mail. I'm not an expert but i know how to do this on a time frame base.

So what i did was create a console command (ssh command).

This by creating a file :

**Vendor/Namespace/Console/Command/CommandSomething.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Namespace\Console\Command;

use Vendor\Namespace\Model\YourCustomSendingModel;

use Magento\Framework\App\Area;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class CommandSomething extends Command
{

    protected $_state;
    protected $_YourCustomSendingModel;

    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        YourCustomSendingModel $YourCustomSendingModel,
        $name = null
    )
    {
        $state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_WEBAPI_REST);
        $this->_YourCustomSendingModel  = $YourCustomSendingModel ;
        parent::__construct($name);
    }


    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('command:subcommand')->setDescription('Send mail');
    }


    protected function execute(
        InputInterface $input,
        OutputInterface $output
    )
    {
        $output->writeln('Sending Mails ...');
        $mail= $this->_YourCustomSendingModel->SendMail();
        $output->writeln($mail);
    }
}
```

Now we need to register that ssh command

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="subcommand" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Console\Command\CommandSomething</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments></type>
</config>
```

This is to trigger something on action (ssh command action). 
We can now set a timeframe with our .crontab file (provided by host or you need to configure cron yourself on your own server):

```
*/5 * * * * php -d "memory_limit=2048M"  /site/www/bin/magento command:subcommand >> /site/www/var/log/mailsend.cron.log&
```

If you wish to do it after an event you can use a plugin with After method instead of all this :

[Plugin interceptors](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Long story short you will need something to trigger everything. I use this for syncing products

Just add your Custom mail sending model there.

Now i do not know which Model or Controller or anything you need to extend to send out a Mail but there is a fille that is responsible for sending out mails within Magento. A quick Google will provide you that information.

In your CustomSendingModel :

**Vendor/Namespace/Model/CustomSendingModel.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor/Namespace/Model;

use ** class that is responsible for sending mails which we will call 'MailSendClass' for now **

use ** the class that you made to get the Rest API information which we will call GetApi for now **



class CustomSendingModel extends MailSendClass {

$protected $_getapi;

public function __construct(
GetApi $getapi,
parent construct here)
{
$this->_getapi = $getapi;
parent::....
}

// note : if you don't know how to construct constructors i highly recommend buying Magicento for PhP storm that will autocomplete that for you

public function SendMail(){

$data = $this->_getapi->FunctionThatReturnsData();

.....

// use mailsending functions from here to past in the data and return that and execute the mailsending from that class.

}
```

I know that i'm not giving you a copy/paste solution but that would require me to develop your module. Which i won't do. But this is the logistics that you need. You need a trigger (cron trigger or plugin trigger) that triggers the mailsending where you give your data from your REST ApI. Mailsending is usually done with Cron to prevent overload.